# The device tree header verification error was encountered during uboot startup

Tags: linux, kernel, u-boot, device-tree

I have a problem when using orangepi3.

I have an image that can be used under normal circumstances,

but the following problem occasionally occurs.
Once this problem occurs, the image burned in this time can no longer be used, and only the burned image can be reproduced

The following errors are reported during uboot startup.

```
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0
no mmc device at slot 0
mmc2(part 0) is current device
2512 bytes read in 5 ms (490.2 KiB/s)
## Executing script at 43100000
U-boot loaded from SD
Boot script loaded from mmc
** Bad device mmc 0 **
** File not found /boot/dtb/sunxi/sun50i-h6-orangepi3.dtb **
libfdt fdt_check_header(): FDT_ERR_BADMAGIC
8247895 bytes read in 404 ms (19.5 MiB/s)
19425352 bytes read in 945 ms (19.6 MiB/s)
```

but i am sure this file is exists;
Because when this error exists, I enter uboot and print the device tree. It can print correctly, but executing the command boot will still report this error.

And I checked the file system afterwards and found that the file exists in the path
.

I checked the uboot source code and found this error in the function fdt_check_header

```
int fdt_check_header(const void *fdt)
{
        if (fdt_magic(fdt) == FDT_MAGIC) {
                /* Complete tree */
                if (fdt_version(fdt) < FDT_FIRST_SUPPORTED_VERSION)
                        return -FDT_ERR_BADVERSION;
                if (fdt_last_comp_version(fdt) > FDT_LAST_SUPPORTED_VERSION)
                        return -FDT_ERR_BADVERSION;
        } else if (fdt_magic(fdt) == FDT_SW_MAGIC) {
                /* Unfinished sequential-write blob */
                if (fdt_size_dt_struct(fdt) == 0)
                        return -FDT_ERR_BADSTATE;
        } else {
                return -FDT_ERR_BADMAGIC;
        }

        return 0;
}
```

But in uboot init_sequence_f exe reserve_fdt also have the verification of the device tree header,and the verification has passed.
but in uboot autoboot_command  run_command_list cmd_list an error occurred in the device tree header checked.resulting in failure to enter the kernel correctly.

Before entering FDT_ check_ I added a print function before the header function

Before entering the function fdt_check_header() I add a print like following in reserve_fdt()

static int reserve_fdt(void)
{

```
/*
 * If the device tree is sitting immediate above our image then we
 * must relocate it. If it is embedded in the data section, then it
 * will be relocated with other data.
 */

if (gd->fdt_blob) {
    pr_msg("reserve_fdt fdt_check_headeris %d\n",fdt_magic(gd->fdt_blob));
    if(fdt_check_header(gd->fdt_blob) != 0)
    {
        pr_msg("fdt header check error\n");
        return -1;
    }
    //reserve memory for expand dtb ,because cmd_fdt will update the base dtb
    gd->fdt_size = ALIGN(fdt_totalsize(gd->fdt_blob) + 0x1000, 32);
    fdt_set_totalsize((void*)gd->fdt_blob,gd->fdt_size);

    gd->start_addr_sp -= gd->fdt_size * 2;
    gd->new_fdt = map_sysmem(gd->start_addr_sp, gd->fdt_size);
    debug("Reserving %lu Bytes for FDT at: %08lx\n",
          gd->fdt_size, gd->start_addr_sp);
}

return 0;
```

}

And in function fdt_valid() add too;

```
static int fdt_valid(struct fdt_header **blobp)

{
    const void *blob = *blobp;
    int err;

    if (blob == NULL) {
        printf ("The address of the fdt is invalid (NULL).\n");
        return 0;
    }
    printf("fdt_valid fdt_check_header is %d\n",fdt_magic(blob));
    err = fdt_check_header(blob);
    if (err == 0)
        return 1;   /* valid */

    if (err < 0) {
        printf("libfdt fdt_check_header(): %s", fdt_strerror(err));
        /*
         * Be more informative on bad version.
         */
        if (err == -FDT_ERR_BADVERSION) {
            if (fdt_version(blob) <
                FDT_FIRST_SUPPORTED_VERSION) {
                printf (" - too old, fdt %d < %d",
                    fdt_version(blob),
                    FDT_FIRST_SUPPORTED_VERSION);
            }
            if (fdt_last_comp_version(blob) >
                FDT_LAST_SUPPORTED_VERSION) {
                printf (" - too new, fdt %d > %d",
                    fdt_version(blob),
                    FDT_LAST_SUPPORTED_VERSION);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
        *blobp = NULL;
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
    }
```

Then,when the error occurs,the log is as follows:

```
U-Boot 2014.07-orangepi (Oct 29 2021 - 09:07:58) Xunlong Software

[1.947]uboot commit : b65841975dcb31f64a2c69344f60db12b98791ae

[1.947]secure enable bit: 0
[1.947]normal mode: with secure monitor
I2C:   ready
[1.949]pmbus:   ready
[1.949][ARISC] :arisc initialize
[1.975][ARISC] :arisc para ok
[SCP] :sunxi-arisc driver begin startup 2
[SCP] :arisc version: []
[SCP] :sunxi-arisc driver v1.10 is starting
[1.987][ARISC] :sunxi-arisc driver startup succeeded
[1.989]PMU: AXP806
[1.989]PMU: AXP806 found
[1.989]bat_vol=0, ratio=0
[1.989]set pc_bias(1) bias:1800
[1.989]set pg_bias(5) bias:1800
[1.989]set power on vol to default
[1.989]dcdca_vol = 1000, onoff=1
[1.993]aldo2_vol = 3300, onoff=1
[1.998]bldo3_vol = 1800, onoff=1
[2.002]cldo2_vol = 3300, onoff=1
[2.006]cldo3_vol = 3300, onoff=1
[2.010]find power_sply to end
[2.010]cant find pll setting(1320M) from  pll table,use default(408M)
[2.012]PMU: cpux 408 Mhz,AXI=204 Mhz
[2.013]PLL6=600 Mhz,AHB1=200 Mhz, APB1=100Mhz MBus=400Mhz
[2.017]DRAM:  1 GiB
[2.019]reserve_fdt fdt_check_headeris -804389139
[2.026]fdt addr: 0x79ccb0e0
[2.026]gd->fdt_size: 0x1a6c0
[2.030]Relocation Offset is: 34e03000
[2.095]gic: sec monitor mode
[2.095]line:180 func:check_ir_boot_recovery start
[2.095]ir boot recovery not used
[2.095][key recovery] no use
[2.096][box standby] read rtc = 0x0
[2.096][box standby] start_type = 0x1
[2.096][box standby] to kernel
[2.096]workmode = 0,storage type = 2
[2.098]MMC:      2
SUNXI SD/MMC: 2
[mmc]: [0-60|61]
[mmc]: [0-51|52]
[mmc]: [7-48|42]
[mmc]: [0-11|12] [26-29|4] [34-50|17]
[mmc]: [0-48|49] [54-56|3] [58-63|6]
[mmc]: [0-26|27] [54-63|10]
[mmc]: [0-58|59]
[mmc]: [6-51|46] [53-58|6]
[mmc]: [1-7|7] [9-56|48]
[mmc]: [1-26|26]
Normal
[6.618]MMC:      2
SUNXI SD/MMC: 2, SUNXI SD/MMC: 2
[6.624]sunxi flash init ok
[6.624]hdmi hdcp not enable!
Using default environment

[6.625]inter uboot shell
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0
no mmc device at slot 0
mmc2(part 0) is current device
2512 bytes read in 5 ms (490.2 KiB/s)
## Executing script at 43100000
U-boot loaded from SD
Boot script loaded from mmc
** Bad device mmc 0 **
**** File not found /boot/dtb/sunxi/sun50i-h6-orangepi3.dtb **
fdt_valid fdt_check_header is -1271711085
libfdt fdt_check_header(): FDT_ERR_BADMAGIC
fdt_valid fdt_check_header is -1271711085
libfdt fdt_check_header(): FDT_ERR_BADMAGIC**
8247895 bytes read in 404 ms (19.5 MiB/s)
19425352 bytes read in 945 ms (19.6 MiB/s)
## Booting kernel from Legacy Image at 41000000 ...
   Image Name:
   Image Type:   ARM Linux Kernel Image (uncompressed)
   Data Size:    19425288 Bytes = 18.5 MiB
   Load Address: 41000000
   Entry Point:  41000000
   Verifying Checksum ... OK
## Loading init Ramdisk from Legacy Image at 43300000 ...
   Image Name:   uInitrd
   Image Type:   ARM Linux RAMDisk Image (gzip compressed)
   Data Size:    8247831 Bytes = 7.9 MiB
   Load Address: 00000000
   Entry Point:  00000000
   Verifying Checksum ... OK
   Loading Kernel Image ... OK
   reserving fdt memory region: addr=40020000 size=800
   reserving fdt memory region: addr=48000000 size=1000000
   reserving fdt memory region: addr=48100000 size=4000
   reserving fdt memory region: addr=48104000 size=1000
   reserving fdt memory region: addr=48105000 size=1000
   reserving fdt memory region: addr=79ccb0e0 size=18f20
   Loading Ramdisk to 49822000, end 49fffa17 ... OK
   Using Device Tree in place at 44000000, end 4401d6bf
[8.736]disp_ioctl, display not init yet
[8.736]disp_ioctl, display not init yet

Starting kernel ...

INFO:    BL3-1: Next image address = 0x41000000
INFO:    BL3-1: Next image spsr = 0x3c5
WARNING: Unimplemented Standard Service Call: 0xc0000026
```

and the number fdt_check_headeris -804389139 id normol;

This why?
Why is the verification still correct in the front, but an error occurs in the back?

Have you ever encountered this problem? Or can you give me some advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are the report logs same when each reboot ?

If same, the DTB in hardware storage is fine.

And you should be concerned about memory overwriting between two `fdt_magic` function calls.

Comment: Most of the time, the image can be started normally. 

Only occasionally, the device tree file cannot be found.

 However, once this problem occurs, the image cannot be used normally again 

and must  be burned again

Comment: When the problem occurs the first fdt header check is ok, but the second check failed.I thought it should be the data in memory be changed.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me. I'll look at the code again.

Answer (score 0):

You're on `2014.07`  which is missing both support for modern ext4 filesystem images as well as the warning / refusal to mount modern ext4 filesystem images that have features enabled by default that show symptoms such as "file I know exists, I can see it in Linux, are not found".  Please upgrade to current U-Boot.